# Use str to set attribute for module in python

Tags: string, image-processing, attributes, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to learn python (using python3.2), and right now I'm creating a program designed to scale images:

```
from PIL import Image

def newSizeChoice():
    scale = input('Please enter the scale to be applied to the image: x')
    while float(scale) <= 0:
        scale = input('Invalid: scale must be positive. Please enter a new scale: x')
    return float(scale)

def bestFilter(x):
    if x < 1:
        filter = 'ANTIALIAS'
    elif x == 2:
        filter = 'BILINEAR'
    elif x == 4:
        filter = 'BICUBIC'
    else:
        filter = 'NEAREST'
    return filter

def resize(img, width, height, scale, filter):
    width = width * scale
    height = height * scale
    newimg = img.resize((width, height), Image.filter)
    newimg.save('images\\LargeCy.png')
    newimg.show()

img = Image.open('images\\cy.png')
pix = img.load()
width, height = img.size

scale = float(newSizeChoice())
filter = bestFilter(scale)
resize(img, width, height, scale, filter)
```

It's a little bit of a mess right now, because I'm still working on it, but my problem is that when I set the filter in function 'bestFilter', I'm not able to use it to set the filter in function 'resize'. The error I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\14davidson_a\Desktop\Projects\Exercises\ImageScaling.py", line 33, in <module>
    resize(img, width, height, scale, filter)
  File "C:\Users\14davidson_a\Desktop\Projects\Exercises\ImageScaling.py", line 23, in resize
    newimg = img.resize((width, height), Image.filter)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Question: Is there a way I can use a string to set the attribute for a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `Image.filter`, which is not defined on the `Image` module. Perhaps you meant to use the `filter` argument of the method instead?

```
def resize(img, width, height, scale, filter):
    width = width * scale
    height = height * scale
    newimg = img.resize((width, height), filter)
    newimg.save('images\\LargeCy.png')
    newimg.show()
```

You don't use the `filter` argument for anything else in that method.

You'll need to update your `bestFilter()` function to return a valid `Image` filter:

```
def bestFilter(x):
    if x < 1:
        filter = Image.ANTIALIAS
    elif x == 2:
        filter = Image.BILINEAR
    elif x == 4:
        filter = Image.BICUBIC
    else:
        filter = Image.NEAREST
    return filter
```

You could simplify that function by using a mapping:

```
_scale_to_filter = {
    1: Image.ANTIALIAS,
    2: Image.BILINEAR,
    4: Image.BICUBIC,
}
def bestFilter(x):
    return _scale_to_filter.get(x, Image.NEAREST)
```

Comment: When I tried that I got [an error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1394475/). I was using Image.filter since it had worked before when I manually set the filter (e.g. Image.NEAREST, Image.ANTIALIAS, etc.); I got it from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216637/resize-an-image-python)

Comment: `Image.NEAREST` and `Image.ANTIALIAS` are constants, and you can refer directly to those. You can set `filter` to one of those, then pass that to `resize`. But `Image.filter` is not a defined attribute of the `Image` module.

Comment: Ah, yes, that worked, and I think I get why now. Thanks! EDIT: That also solved the issue I was having with downsizing earlier, for some reason. Thanks again!